# How to reference a view outside of a struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code passes a `handler` to `ActionView`. The handler should execute some things and then write the output to the `TextEditor`.

I assume that somehow the bound variable `output` should be accessed from within the `handler`. How can that be done, or is that the wrong approach altogether?

```swift
struct ActionView: View {
    
    struct Action {
        let handler: ()->()
    }
        
    @State var output: String = "a\nb\nc"
    
    let action: Action
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: action.handler) {
                Label("Action")
            }
            TextEditor(text: $output)
        }
    }
}

struct ActionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let action = ActionView.Action(
            handler: {
                // Do something and write to $output
            })
        ActionView(actions: actions)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t SwiftUI wrappers won’t update body when modified from outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your Action handler to take a `Binding` argument so that the calling code can pass the `@State` property to the action.

```
 struct Action {
    let handler: (Binding<String>)->()
 }
```

and then the button action can pass the property

```
Button("Action") { action.handler($output) }
```

An example of using the view from a parent view

```
ActionView(action: ActionView.Action(handler: {
    $0.wrappedValue = $0.wrappedValue.uppercased()
}))
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer, because it actually passes the reference of the property to the handler, so it can be modified. Very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Your can code can be made to work with only a few minor changes:

- Action handler should return something, preferably a String, that `output` can be assigned.
- Your button should set `output` equal to the result of the action handler.
- Your model, Action, should be defined outside of `ActionView` so that it is available to the parent.

Here's how those modifications might look in action:

```
struct ActionView: View {

    @State private var output: String = "a\nb\nc"
    let action: Action

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                output = action.handler()
            }) {
                Text("Action")
            }
            TextEditor(text: $output)
        }
    }
}

struct Action {
    let handler: () -> String
}
```

You might then call `ActionView` in a parent like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let myAction = Action(handler: {
        return "d\ne\nf"
    })
    var body: some View {
        ActionView(action: myAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: The note "Your model, Action, should be defined outside of ActionView so that it is available to the parent." is incorrect. It can be accessed with `ActionView.Action`.